# Profiling TS-based Jest tests

Tags: jestjs

I have a Typescript-based React project in which I am running jest tests (also in TS).  I can run tests fine but am trying to profile the performance of some which take quite a long time to run.  I have tried using [Chrome Devtools to attach to the tests](https://jestjs.io/docs/troubleshooting), which it does, however it fails due to it being TS and not plain Js.  Is there any way I can profile my tests individually to see where the performance issue is occurring?  Using VS Code.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of a React project, it was just a regular TypeScript library for me, but I bet this also works for your use-case. I am leaving this here, in case it's usable, or for future me.

The ONLY solution I found that worked was manually setting up the profiler [v8-profiler-next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v8-profiler-next).

```js
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as v8Profiler from 'v8-profiler-next';
v8Profiler.setGenerateType(1);
const title = 'good-name';

describe('Should be able to generate with inputs', () => {
  v8Profiler.startProfiling(title, true);
  afterAll(() => {
    const profile = v8Profiler.stopProfiling(title);
    profile.export(function (error, result: any) {
      // if it doesn't have the extension .cpuprofile then
      // chrome's profiler tool won't like it.
      // examine the profile:
      //   Navigate to chrome://inspect
      //   Click Open dedicated DevTools for Node
      //   Select the profiler tab
      //   Load your file
      fs.writeFileSync(`${title}.cpuprofile`, result);
      profile.delete();
    });
  });
  test('....', async () => {
    // Add test
  });
});
```

This then gives you the CPU profile as such, which works fine with TypeScript.

[image]

Comment: I had to change `import v8Profiler from 'v8-profiler-next';` to `import * as v8Profiler from 'v8-profiler-next';`